# PHP Arrays with Datatables

Tags: php, arrays, datatables

I have been playing around with datatables and now have a requirement to filter a table via select/dropdown which should filter one of my columns. My code is:

```
<?php
$urlPriority = $_GET['priority'];
if (empty($urlPriority)) {
  $urlPriority = 'High';
}
$priorityStatus = array('Low'=>'Low Priority', 'Medium'=>'Medium Priority', 'High'=>'High Priority');

echo createSelectControl('Priority', $priorityStatus, $urlPriority, -1, false, 'reload();')
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reload() {
  var priority = $("#Priority").val();
  location.search = '?priority=' + priority;

}
</script>
```

I added the line of code to my sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from [table_name]
WHERE ... AND
Priority = '" . mssql_escape($urlPriority) . "' AND
etc AND
etc ";
```

This works great when selecting one of the options.

All I need now is for the user to be able to select all options, including Low, Medium and High, I have tried all methods i can think of but it just returns an empty table?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: what this function do ? `createSelectControl`

Comment: hi, this creates the select tag from an external php routine

Comment: if createSelectControl is printing the combo select just make it multiple and arrage the $_GET['priority'] and the select to treat a multiple selection

Comment: koalaok - this routine prints to other elements of my application that i do not want to have this function.
I was hoping that i had just overlooked a simple solution to add an additional array, such as 'All'=>'  ',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution which does exactly what i needed, thought i'd share the JSFiddle

```
   initComplete: function() {
  var column = this.api().column(2);

  var select = $('<select class="filter"><option value=""></option></select>')
    .appendTo('#selectTriggerFilter')
    .on('change', function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      //column.search(val ? '^' + $(this).val() + '$' : val, true, false).draw();
      column.search(val).draw()
    });

   var offices = []; 
   column.data().toArray().forEach(function(s) {
        s = s.split(',');
      s.forEach(function(d) {
        if (!~offices.indexOf(d)) {
            offices.push(d)
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');                         }
      })
   })    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1Ly9uxf/15/

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
if($urlPriority!="")
{
    //query with priority filter
}
else
{
    //query without priority filter
}
```

if user select priority value assign it to $urlPriority, else make it empty. then it will retrieve every result